# Git: Syncing branches of 2 remote repositories

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am working on project which is on bitbucket. I forked existing repository for my team and we are working on it. Bitbucket automatically shows if my repository is behind source repo and will sync it. But It syncs master branch of source repo with master branch of my repo. But source repo maintainer asked to always sync his develop branch and only commit to my develop branch. So I want to know how to sync develop branch of source repo with my repo develop branch.

I am not sure if it has something to do with adding 2 remotes and syncing them locally and pushing?

Comment: bitbucket does not do anything itself. Have you checked how to merge and push in git?

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the exact remote branch with the statement:

`git checkout -b origin/develop`

If you already have a local `develop` branch that earlier pulled from master, you can edit its remote upstream branch by this command :

`git checkout develop`

`git branch -u origin/develop`

This will cause all your future commits to be pushed to the upstream `develop` branch.

Comment: I have 2 repositories here . lets say repo-1 and repo-2 . I have a local copy of repo-2. I just want to work on develop branch of repo-2 but want "develop" of repo-2 updated as "develop" of repo-1

Answer (score 0):

add two separate remote with repo name so there is no confusion if you have same code on both repo  .Then if need pull from repo1 use

```
git pull repo1 develop
```

then

```
git push repo2 develop
```

To add multiple remote use

```
git remote add remote-name remote-url
```

To rename existing remote use

```
git remote set-url remote-name remote-url
```